# iOS – Facebook SDK 3.1.1 access alert doesn't show after app is removed from facebook.com

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-ios-sdk

If remove my app from [Facebook App Center](http://www.facebook.com/appcenter/my/) and then I try to authorize my app with

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                         }];
```

The alert ("Don't allow", "OK") that should be displayed requesting for access is not shown, instead when the completion handler is called FBSessionState will be `FBSessionStateOpen` which is wrong.

The second time I try to authorize it will always show the access alert correctly.

Am I the only one experiencing this? Is there a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We now have better error handling in our new SDK 3.2.
Please check out our new SDK release 3.2 here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/02/25/facebook-sdk-3-2-for-ios/